# pip install failing on local whl file

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I've inherited a Python project, when I load it into PyCharm and request "Install all Packages" it gives me the very unhelpful "Can't install" error for pretty much every package listed.
From the command line, if I execute `pip install -r requirements.txt` it tells me

`ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'blah @ file:blah-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl' (from line 130 of requirements.txt)`

The requirements.txt file at that point looks like this:

```
blah @ file:blah-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl \
    --hash=sha256:31165a68607e992f3936602ef3d8fed717ddba8dad8d43cc4c6ca5f0f6340588
```

OK, so it isn't liking loading a whl file from a local folder.

The documentation I can find online ([pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/), [requirements file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/)) has scanty information on loading a package from a whl file, although in the [requirements file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) document it does show simply specifying the path to the whl file on its own line in the requirements.txt file.

If I make that change in my requirements.txt file, pip install is much happier, but now PyCharm is very angry.  It displays that line in red and "show context options" gives me this very unhelpful statement: `Inspection 'Package is not installed' has no quick-fixes for this problem.`

I did see a reference online that suggested that pip install really only likes URLs, and they suggested adding the two slashes after the "file:":

```
blah @ file://blah-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl
```

PyCharm's editor likes this (doesn't show any errors) but doesn't recognize it (the right-click context menu doesn't give an "install" option) and pip install agrees it's bad:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\blah-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl'
```

So if I stick with the "blah @ file:blah.whl" format, PyCharm's editor thinks it's OK but then can't actually install anything, and if I change to the "blah.whl" format it installs using pip install but PyCharm is very unhappy.

Is there a format for installing a package from a whl file on the local disk that makes both pip install and PyCharm happy?

EDIT

Apparently this is a [known PyCharm bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52562), although it was reported a year ago and is just sitting there.  Trying the workaround listed there didn't help with the latest PyCharm (2022.3.3), it always displays the first line in red:

```
blah==1.1.15
blah @ file:blah-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl \
    --hash=sha256:31164b68606e992f3936702ef3d8fed717ddba8dad8d43cc4c6ca5f0f6340588
```